# Why do I need to supply a password for `sudo`, when I've added my account to /etc/sudoers with NOPASSWD:ALL?

Tags: sudo

On Ubuntu 18.04 (x64), I've added my account `myusr` to `/etc/sudoers` as follows:

```
myusr ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, I still need to supply a password for using `sudo` after inactivity/reboot.

Comment: Space between `NOPASSWD:` and `ALL`.

Comment: Doesn't work - also `visudo` should have caught such syntax error.

Comment: Are there other sudo rules below this one that match your account in some way?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l`?